# How can I save a relationship entry to a pivot table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I have created some relationships where 2 models work together, currently they are `Offer` and `OfferDay`. I have created 2 tables one for Offers and one for OfferDays. Here are the migrations:

offers

```
class CreateOffersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('offers', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('offer_title');
            $table->string('offer headline');
            $table->string('offer_subheader');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->text('offer_terms');
            $table->string('featured_date');
            $table->boolean('is_featured');
            $table->string('distance_to_offer');
            $table->string('offer_end_time');
            $table->string('offer_start_time');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('offers');
    }
}
```

I then have a migration that runs to create the days for the relationship to work and this holds the day name and the day id in the table where I have seeded the database with days already. Here's the migration schema:

offer_days

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('offer_days', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('day');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This forms the basis of the relationships and the data we have got. The next bit is making them work and when adding an offer making sure I can populate the pivot table with the correct data that relates to offers and offer_days. Below are the 2 models I have got setup with all the correct `$fillable` attributes for the relationships to work:

Offer

```
        protected $fillable = ['id','venue_id','offer_day_id','offer_id','day','venue_address','is_featured','repeater_days','image', 'venue_description', 'offer_headline','offer_subheader','offer_terms','venue_phone_number','venue_website', 'venue_name', 'venue_headline','venue_description','venue_latitude','venue_longitude','days','offer_when','offer_end_time','offer_start_time','offer_start_date','offer_end_date','featured_date','current_time','current_date'];

/**
     * Get the offers for the offer.
     */
    public function offerdays()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\OfferDay', 'offer_day_offer', 'offer_day_id', 'offer_id');
    }
```

OfferDay

```
protected $fillable = ['offer_id','offer_day_id'];
    /**
     * Get the offer days for the offer.
     */

    public function offers()
    {
        //return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer');

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer', 'offer_day_offer', 'offer_id', 'offer_day_id');
    }
```

I have then created the pivot tables to correspond with this like so:

```
class CreateOfferDayOfferPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('offer_day_offer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('offer_day_id')->unsigned()->index();
            // $table->foreign('offer_day_id')->references('id')->on('offer_days')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('offer_id')->unsigned()->index();
            // $table->foreign('offer_id')->references('id')->on('offers')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['offer_day_id', 'offer_id']);
        });

        Schema::table('offer_day_offer', function($table) {
           $table->foreign('offer_id')->references('id')->on('offers');
       });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('offer_day_offer');
    }
}
```

In my controller I have setup the save method which should work like so:

```
if ($validation->fails()) {
            return redirect('offers')->with('message', $validation->errors());
        } else {
            $file = Input::file('image');
            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H')."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();

            $path = public_path('images/offers/' . $filename);
            Image::make($file->getRealPath())
              ->save($path);

            $venue = Input::get('venue_id');
            $day = Input::get('day');

            $data['image'] = url('/') . '/' . 'images/offers/'.$filename;
            if($days){
                $d = implode(',', $days);
                $data['days'] = $d;
            }
            $data['venue_id'] = $venue;
            $data['day'] = $day;
            $offer->offerdays()->attach(['offer_day_id' => 13, 'offer_id' => 530]);
            Offer::create( $data );
            return redirect('offers')->with('message', 'Offer added!');
        }
```

This `$offer->offerdays()->attach(['offer_day_id' => 13, 'offer_id' => 530]);` is the important bit but for some reason I am getting this error below:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`offer_day_offer`, CONSTRAINT `offer_day_offer_offer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `offers` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `offer_day_offer` (`offer_day_id`, `offer_id`) values (, 13), (, 530))
```

Can someone try and shed light onto this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this, `$offer->offerdays()->attach($offer->id,['offer_day_id' => 13, 'offer_id' => 530]);`

Comment: ah that didn't populate the pivot table for `offer_day_offer` but i got no errors soits not exactly worked

Comment: You are certain there is an OfferDay with id of 13 and an Offer with id of 530?